# return value the ng-model of a select within the repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ngmodel

I problem return value `ng-model="selectStates"` of a select within the repeat!

Where this commented, was another attempt.

```
<div ng-controller="coursesCtrl">

    <form name="formFilters" id="formFilters">
        <div ng-repeat="filter in filters">
            <div ng-switch="filter.type">
                <div ng-switch-when="dropdown">
                    <h5 class="menu-filter-sidebars--title">{{filter.title}}</h5>

                        <select name="selectStates" id="selectStates" ng-options="option.name for option in filter.inputs" **`ng-model="selectStates"`** >
                         <!--  <option value="" > Selecione o Estado </option>
                          <option data-ng-repeat="item in filter.inputs" value="{{item.uf}}">{{item.Estado+' - '+item.uf}}</option> -->
                        </select>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </form> 

     <div class="test" > {{selectStates}} </div>

</div>
```

Comment: share your JSON object to debug easily

Answer (score 0):

Change your ng-model="selectStates" to ng-model="filter.selectStates", that should help.

Answer (score 0):

### Always Have a Dot in Your `ng-model`

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't even need to know it is happening... until you try **2-way data binding** (i.e., form elements, ng-model) **to a primitive** (e.g., number, string, boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works. New AngularJS developers often do not realize that `ng-repeat`, `ng-switch`, `ng-view` and `ng-include` all create new child scopes, so the problem often shows up when these directives are involved. (See [this PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/zZfUQN?p=preview) for a quick illustration of the problem.)
>
> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of **[always have a '.' in your ng-models](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m)** – watch 3 minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with `ng-switch`.
>
> Having a '.' in your models will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play. So, use
>
> ```
> <input type="text" ng-model="someObj.prop1"> rather than 
> <input type="text" ng-model="prop1">.
> ```

-- [AngularJS Wiki -- Understanding Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)